# swing dont't finish after exception

Tags: java, swing, awk

why doesn't this program finish after null pointer exception? Eclipse shows unfinished AWK thread of event queue. How can I finish it?

```
class MyFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    private String s;
        public MyFrame() {
        pack();
        s.toString();
    }
}
public class Test4 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        new MyFrame();
    }
}
```

Comment: I did it but I would like to know the reason for this behavior. When I comment pack() it works fine. What is the reason?

Comment: `pack` creates a native peer and starts the Event Dispatching Thread...

Comment: You are creating and mutating Swing components on the `main` thread and not the EDT. This is a violation of Swing's threading policy. Don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to achieve similar behaviour as

`setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);`

you can do exception handling and use `System.exit(0);`

that will not only close the `JFrame` but also shut down the entire application.

Answer (score 0):

Even after the window is closed, the method main continues.
You need On close window: 
  dispose(); 
  System.exit(0);

Comment: When exception in the constructor JForm var is null and I can't call dispose(). But AWT thread started.